# how to build specific framework in native android for applications having same functionality?

Tags: android, frameworks

I want to know that, Is there any way to build a specific framework for applications having same functionality?
Or I have to replace the code always with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).